# How to use Twitter Search API with Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, twitter, mapreduce

I am new to Hadoop. I've been learning a lot about hadoop lately. I've successfully used Streaming API and got twitter data into HDFS. Now I am trying to use Search API so I can get historical tweets but I can't find any examples online. There were bunch of examples for Streaming Api but couldn't find one for Search API.

Comment: Twitter Search API endpoint only returns tweets for the last 7 days approximately. The alternative is to contract Gnip Historical Search (http://support.gnip.com/apis/historical_api/)

Comment: @LuisCipriani I know, I just wanted to figure out how to the Search API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention the programming language so I'm assuming you're going to use Java. [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html) library is recommended and its documentation has some Search examples, such as:

```
public class SearchTweets {
/**
 * Usage: java twitter4j.examples.search.SearchTweets [query]
 *
 * @param args search query
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length < 1) {
        System.out.println("java twitter4j.examples.search.SearchTweets [query]");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    try {
        Query query = new Query(args[0]);
        QueryResult result;
        do {
            result = twitter.search(query);
            List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
            for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText());
            }
        } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Available at Github repo: https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/search/SearchTweets.java

Also, make sure you understand how to [Work with Timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines).